# Can I output boolean based on values in a list?

Tags: json, csv, boolean, jq, indicator

Edit: I used the solution provided by @peak to do the following:

```
$ jq -r --argjson whitelist '["role1", "role2"]' '
select(has("roles") and any(.roles[]; . == "role1" or . == "role2"))
| (reduce ."roles"[] as $r ({}; .[$r]=true)) as $roles
| [.email, .username, .given_name, .family_name, ($roles[$whitelist[]]
| . != null)]
| @csv
' users.json
```

Added the `select()` to filter out users who haven't onboarded yet and don't have any roles, and to ensure the users included in the output have at least one of the target roles.

Scenario: user profiles as JSON docs, where each profile has a list object with their assigned roles. Example:

```
{
  "username": "janedoe",
  "roles": [
    "role1",
    "role4",
    "role5"
  ]
}
```

The actual data file is an ndjson file, one user object as above per line.

I am only interested in specific roles, say `role1`, `role3`, and `role4`. I want to produce a CSV formatted as:

```
username,role1?,role3?,role4?
```

e.g.,

```
janedoe,true,false,true
```

The part I haven't figured out is how to output booleans or Y / N in response to the values in the list object. Is this something I can do in `jq` itself?

Comment: Your select statement is not what you think it is. Consider instead: `select(has("roles") and any(.roles[] == $whitelist[]; true))`.  Please fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your input, the invocation:

```
jq -r --argjson whitelist '["role1", "role3", "role4"]' '
  (["username"] + $whitelist),
  [.username, ($whitelist[] as $w | .roles | index([$w]) != null)]
  | @csv
'
```

produces:

```
"username","role1","role3","role4"
"janedoe",true,false,true
```

#### Notes:

1. The second last line of the jq filter above could be shortened to:

   `[.username, (.roles | index($whitelist[]) != null)]`
2. Presumably if there were more than one user, you'd only want
   the header row once, in which case the above solution
   would need to be tweaked.

### Using IN/1

Because `index/1` is not as efficient as it might be,
you might like to consider this alternative:

```
  (["username"] + $whitelist),
  (.roles as $roles | [.username, ($whitelist[] | IN($roles[]) )])
  | @csv
```

### Using a JSON dictionary

If the number of roles was very large, then it would probably be more
efficient to construct a JSON dictionary to avoid repeated linear lookups:

```
  (reduce .roles[] as $r ({}; .[$r]=true)) as $roles
  | (["username"] + $whitelist),
    [.username, ($roles[$whitelist[]] != null)]
  | @csv
```

### With ndjson as input

For efficiency, and to ensure there's just one header, you could use `inputs` with the -n command-line option.  Adding the extra fields mentioned in the revised Q, you might end up with:

```
jq -nr --argjson whitelist '["role1", "role2"]' '
  ["email", "username", "given_name", "family_name"] as $greenlist
  | ($greenlist + $whitelist),
    (inputs 
     | select(has("roles") and any(.roles[] == $whitelist[]; true))
     | (reduce ."roles"[] as $r ({}; .[$r]=true)) as $roles
     | [ .[$greenlist[]], ($roles[$whitelist[]] != null) ])
  | @csv
' users.json
```

Comment: I getting an interesting side effect: for some users I get one line of output for each role that they have. 5 roles = 5 identical lines in the output. But this only happens for some users. At the moment I am not sure what is different about them, if anything. Easy enough to fix by running through `sort` and `uniq`.

Comment: Your `select` statement is not what you think it is.  Consider instead:  `select(any(.roles[]; . == "r" or . == "s"))`

Comment: Seems I still need the `has()` clause, b/c some of the entries don't have the `roles[]` list. Does that make sense? W/o `has()` I get "Cannot iterate over null" on some entries. This seems to work (expected number of results, no duplicates): `select(has("roles") and any(.roles[]; ...`. The data file is `ndjson` if that makes a difference.

Comment: By all means include the `has` condition (as I suggested in the comment attached directly to the Q), though you might find `select(.roles and any(...))` sufficient.